# String modification application

Tags: c#, strings, .net, csv

Below is working code of a semi complete program.  Its purpose is to take an input string of any type and modify it based on rules defined for each type.  So in this example I pass it a string in CSV format and modify some of the fields.

My questions are

1. Can the use of interfaces be improved?
2. How can I handle different string modification patterns (I currently make it work by using `IStringModificationPattern` - but I want to extend this to other types like HTML)?
3. What design changes/ additions can I make to integrate the string modification pattern into a configuration class (i.e. using an XML file based settings)?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StringModificationTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //usage example
            //
            string inputText = "CSV,field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,,,,";

            StringModifier SM = new StringModifier();

            string outputText = SM.ModifyString(inputText);

        }
    }
```

> **StringModifier** class

```
    public class StringModifier
    {
        private List<IStringType> RegisteredTypes = new List<IStringType>();
        private IStringModificationPattern ModificationPattern;

        public StringModifier()
        {
            RegisterTypes();
        }

        private void RegisterTypes()
        {
            RegisteredTypes = TypeFactory.GetTypeList();
        }

        public string ModifyString(string str)
        {
            ///sets the message and sets the Modification pattern
            IString detectedStr = DetectStringType(str);

            ///returns the modified string
            return detectedStr.Modify(ModificationPattern);
        }

        private IString DetectStringType(string str)
        {
            IString msg = new NullString(str);

            for (int i = 0; i < RegisteredTypes.Count; i++)
            {
                if (str.StartsWith(RegisteredTypes[i].start))
                {
                    //set string type
                    msg = RegisteredTypes[i].getNewInstance(str);

                    //set modification pattern
                    ModificationPattern = RegisteredTypes[i].MODPattern;
                }

            }

            return msg;

        }

    }
```

> **TypeFactory** static class

```
    internal static class TypeFactory
    {
        public static List<IStringType> GetTypeList()
        {
            List<IStringType> types = new List<IStringType>();
            types.AddRange(from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                           from t in assembly.GetTypes()
                           where t.IsClass && t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IStringType))
                           select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IStringType);

            return types;
        }
    }
```

> **IStringType** interface

```
    public interface IStringType
    {
        string start { get;  }
        IString getNewInstance(string STR);
        IStringModificationPattern MODPattern { get; }
    }
```

> **IStringType Implementations**

```
    public class CSVType : IStringType
    {
        public string start { get { return @"CSV,"; } }

        public IStringModificationPattern MODPattern { get { return new CSV_StringModificationPattern(); } }

        public IString getNewInstance(string str)
        {
            return (IString)(new CSVString(str));
        }
    }

    public class HTMLStringType : IStringType
    {
        public string start { get { return @"<HTML>"; } }

        public IStringModificationPattern MODPattern { get { return new HTML_StringModificationPattern(); } }

        public IString getNewInstance(string str)
        {
            return (IString)(new HTMLString(str));
        }

    }
```

> **IString** interface

```
    public interface IString
    {
        string STR { get; }
        string Modify(IStringModificationPattern MODPattern);

    }
```

> **IString implementations**

```
    public class CSVString : IString
    {
        public string STR { get; set; }
        public List<string> CSVFields { get; set; }

        public CSVString(string str)
        {
            STR = str;
            CSVFields = new List<string>();
            CSVFields.AddRange(str.Split(','));
        }

        public string Modify(IStringModificationPattern MODPattern)
        {
            string output = STR;

            foreach (int i in MODPattern.location)
            {
                CSVFields[i] = "BLAH";
            }

            //rebuild string
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < CSVFields.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(CSVFields[i]);
                if (i != CSVFields.Count - 1)
                    sb.Append(',');
            }
            output = sb.ToString();

            return output;
        }
    }

    public class HTMLString : IString
    {
        public string STR { get; set; }
        public HTMLString(string str)
        {
            STR = str;
        }

        public string Modify(IStringModificationPattern MODPattern)
        {
            string output = STR;



            return output;
        }

    }

    public class NullString : IString
    {
        public string STR { get; set; }
        public NullString(string str)
        {
            STR = str;
        }

        public string Modify(IStringModificationPattern MODPattern)
        {
            string output = STR;
            //Do nothing
            return output;
        }

    }
```

> **IStringModificationPattern** interface

```
    public interface IStringModificationPattern
    {
        List<int> location { get; set; }
    }
```

> **IStringModificationPattern implementations**

```
    public class CSV_StringModificationPattern : IStringModificationPattern
    {
        //defines the fields that need to be modified
        public List<int> location { get; set; }

        public CSV_StringModificationPattern()
        {
            location = new List<int>();
            location.Add(2);
            location.Add(5);
        }
    }

    public class HTML_StringModificationPattern : IStringModificationPattern
    {
        public List<int> location { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> **EDIT:** Revised Code taking into consideration feedback below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StringModificationTest2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //usage example
            //
            string inputText = "CSV,field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,,,,";

            StringModifier SM = new StringModifier();

            string outputText = SM.Modify(inputText);
        }
    }

    public class StringModifier
    {
        private readonly List<IStringModificationPattern> _registeredPatterns;
        private readonly StringPatternDetector Detector;

        public StringModifier()
        {
            _registeredPatterns = StringModificationPatternFactory.GetTypeList();
            Detector = new StringPatternDetector();
        }

        public string Modify(string inputValue)
        {
            //get the modification pattern that belongs to this string, and the string object
            IStringModificationPattern Modificationpattern = Detector.DetectPattern(this._registeredPatterns, inputValue);
            IString StringObject = Detector.StringObject;

            //execute correct modification algorithm on the input string
            return StringObject.Modify(Modificationpattern); ;
        }
    }

    public class StringPatternDetector
    {
        private IStringModificationPattern _pattern;

        public IString StringObject { get; private set; }

        public StringPatternDetector()
        {
            StringObject = new DEFAULTString(string.Empty);
        }

        public IStringModificationPattern DetectPattern(List<IStringModificationPattern> registeredPatterns, string value)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < registeredPatterns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (value.StartsWith(registeredPatterns[i].start))
                {
                    _pattern = registeredPatterns[i];
                }
            }

            if (_pattern != null)
                StringObject = _pattern.getNewInstance(value);
            else
                StringObject = new DEFAULTString(value);

            return _pattern;
        }
    }


    internal static class StringModificationPatternFactory
    {
        public static List<IStringModificationPattern> GetTypeList()
        {
            List<IStringModificationPattern> types = new List<IStringModificationPattern>();
            types.AddRange(from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                           from t in assembly.GetTypes()
                           where t.IsClass && t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IStringModificationPattern))
                           select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IStringModificationPattern);

            return types;
        }
    }



    public interface IString
    {
        string STR { get; }
        string Modify(IStringModificationPattern MODPattern);
    }

    public class CSVString : IString
    {
        public string STR { get; set; }
        public List<string> CSVFields { get; set; }

        public CSVString(string str)
        {
            STR = str;
            CSVFields = new List<string>();
            CSVFields.AddRange(str.Split(','));
        }

        public string Modify(IStringModificationPattern MODPattern)
        {
            string output = STR;

            foreach (int i in MODPattern.location)
            {
                CSVFields[i] = "BLAH";
            }

            //rebuild string
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < CSVFields.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(CSVFields[i]);
                if (i != CSVFields.Count - 1)
                    sb.Append(',');
            }
            output = sb.ToString();

            return output;
        }
    }

    public class HTMLString : IString
    {
        public string STR { get; set; }
        public HTMLString(string str)
        {
            STR = str;
        }

        public string Modify(IStringModificationPattern MODPattern)
        {
            string output = STR;

            return output;
        }
    }
    public class DEFAULTString : IString
    {
        public string STR { get; set; }
        public DEFAULTString(string str)
        {
            STR = str;
        }

        public string Modify(IStringModificationPattern MODPattern)
        {
            string output = STR;
            //Do nothing
            return output;
        }
    }


    public interface IStringModificationPattern
    {
        string start { get; set; }
        List<int> location { get; set; }
        IString getNewInstance(string value);
    }
    public class CSV_StringModificationPattern : IStringModificationPattern
    {
        public string start { get { return @"CSV,"; } set { this.start = value; } }

        //defines the fields that need to be modified
        public List<int> location { get; set; }

        public CSV_StringModificationPattern()
        {
            location = new List<int>();
            location.Add(2);
            location.Add(5);
        }

        public IString getNewInstance(string value)
        {
            return (IString)(new CSVString(value));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first word that comes to my mind, is *over-engineering*. This looks like a lot of trouble just to get to work with a CSV string, you turn a 10-liner into a party, happiness ensues and neighbors come too, and their friends also, and before you know it you've got 100 lines of code written, to accomplish the exact same thing.

This answer/review does not care about that.

---

> **StringModifier**

The `RegisteredTypes` private field can be made `readonly`, and its naming doesn't match naming conventions for private types. I'd declare it like this:

```
private readonly List<IStringType> _registeredTypes;
```

And initialize it directly in the constructor, and remove the private `RegisterTypes` method altogether:

```
    public StringModifier()
    {
        _registeredTypes = TypeFactory.GetTypeList();
    }
```

While `str` is a well-understood short for `string` and I prefer `str` over `@string`, I think a better name for that parameter could be, simply, `value` - also I'd remove `String` from the method's name, it's in a class called `StringModifier`, it takes a `string` parameter and returns a `string` value. If `Modify` isn't clear enough, I don't know what is!

```
    public string Modify(string value)
    {
        var detectedString = DetectStringType(value);
        return detectedString.Modify(ModificationPattern);
    }
```

I don't think the comments add anything significant in the `ModifyString` method. You have descriptive method names, already doing the job of describing what the code does (and that's good!).

The `DetectStringType` method has opportunities for improvements - the `RegisteredTypes` needs only to be accessed once, and `msg` just seems like an arbitrary name - `result` makes more sense I find:

```
    private IString DetectStringType(string value)
    {
        IString result = new NullString(value);

        for (var i = 0; i < _registeredTypes.Count; i++)
        {
            var type = _registeredTypes[i];
            if (value.StartsWith(type.start))
            {
                result = type.GetNewInstance(value);
                ModificationPattern = type.MODPattern;
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
```

---

> **TypeFactory**

The name is ambiguous, if not overly broad. `StringTypeFactory` would be a better name. This class is clearly infrastructure code. I don't see a need for it to be `static` though: by using it in `StringModifier` the way you are, you have *tightly coupled* the two classes, essentially making `StringModifier` responsible for finding all `IStringType` implementations in the current app domain... which seems like a lot to do for a `StringModifier`.

I'd move this infrastructure code to infrastructure level, and *inject* an `IEnumerable<IStringType>` into `StringModifier`'s constructor:

```
    private readonly IEnumerable<IStringType> _registeredTypes;
    public StringModifier(IEnumerable<IStringType> types)
    {
        _registeredTypes = types;
    }
```

By *infrastructure level*, I mean this:

```
    var inputText = "CSV,field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,,,,";

    var factory = new StringTypeFactory();
    var modifier = new StringModifier(factory.GetTypeList());

    var outputText = modifier.Modify(inputText);
```

..and I know you're not going to like it. Because you probably want to be able to `new` up a `StringModifier` whenever you need to use one - my recommendation is to avoid `new`ing up *anything*. With that many abstractions/interfaces, call me crazy but I'll say that *you're missing an `IStringModifier` abstraction*:

```
public interface IStringModifier
{
    string Modify(string value);
}
```

Now whenever you have a class that wants to use a `StringModifier`, you'll *inject* an `IStringModifier` through that class' constructor, assign a private readonly field, and use that field. This is called *Dependency Injection*, and it greatly helps *decoupling* code and making it more unit-testable. *Creating objects* is a concern on its own, that belongs to *infrastructure code*.

This hypothetical `SomeClass` consumes an `IStringModifier` and shows how *constructor injection* works:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly IStringModifier _modifier;

    public SomeClass(IStringModifier modifier)
    {
        _modifier = modifier;
    }

    public void Foo(string bar)
    {
        var modified = _modifier.Modify(bar);
        // ...
    }
}
```

But back to your code...

---

> **IStringType**

The interface members don't follow casing conventions. Should look more like this:

```
public interface IStringType
{
    string Start { get; }
    IString GetNewInstance(string value);
    IStringModificationPattern Pattern { get; }
}
```

> **IString**

The interface members don't follow casing conventions either:

```
public interface IString
{
    string Value { get; }
    string Modify(IStringModificationPattern pattern);
}
```

---

> **IStringType Implementations**

The `IStringModificationPattern` property smells. All there is to it, is a getter that returns a `new` instance of a *tightly coupled* implementation of the *modification pattern* interface.

> **IString Implementations**

The naming for `NullString` is *dangerously* ambiguous. `VanillaString` could probably work, ...and actually I can't think of any better names than that at the moment! ;)

The `CsvString` (PascalCase FTW!) could use an overloaded constructor that takes a custom separator. Handy when you have string values that may contain commas:

```
    public CsvString(string value) 
        : this(value, ',')
    { /* no op */ }

    public CsvString(string value, char separator)
    {
        Value = value;
        CsvFields = value.Split(separator);
    }
```

Now, your `CsvString` implementation has serious encapsulation issues:

```
    public string STR { get; set; }
    public List<string> CSVFields { get; set; }
```

Nothing prevents client code from overwriting all the hard work put into coming up with a value for `STR`. And nothing prevents client code from throwing away the `CSVFields` and replace it with another `List<string>` reference.

With auto-properties:

```
    public string Value { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Fields { get; private set; }
```

Exposing `Fields` as an `IEnumerable<string>` rather than a `List<string>` allows client code to iterate the fields, but not to `Add` or `Remove` anything. In fact, the intent would be made even clearer with a `readonly` backing field for the fields' reference (no pun intended):

```
    private string _value;
    public string Value { get { return _value; } }

    private readonly IEnumerable<string> _fields;
    public string IEnumerable<string> Fields { get { return _fields; } }
```

The [*Principle of Least Knowledge*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) tells us that if fields are meant to be added or removed from a `CsvString`, then `CsvString` should expose methods to do so (and then the backing field would probably be better of as an `IList<string>`), not letting its clients fiddle with it directly: the type of `_fields` is /*should be* of no concern to the client code.

I renamed `CsvFields` to just `Fields`, because it's a misleading name: there's no separator involved here, it's just ..fields :)

---

> *How can I handle different string modification patterns (I currently make it work by using IStringModificationPattern - but I want to extend this to other types like HTML)?*

Before extending this API, I'd secure *extensibility* as a design concern, and address it with a [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) response.

> *What design changes/ additions can I make to integrate the string modification pattern into a configuration class (i.e. using an XML file based settings)?*

You could probably serialize your `IStringModificationPattern` implementations to XML.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. I added a section at the bottom of my original post with revised code based on your feedback.  Not sure if I made use of all your recommendations correctly but i tried. My idea now was to work from the configuration settings and bringing that into the application.  So the StringModificationpattern classes represent the settings I deserialize from XML (or take from GUI) and I would detect the string and instantiate my objects based on that.  I kept the way the user or application calls this 'api' very simple using a wrapper that does everything behind the scenes.

Comment: Additionally I can look into changing to the IEnumerable and encapsulate better my code, I was just trying to get it structured correctly so it works.